# How to create a server for your app to load files

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure even if i am using the right term "Server". 
So many apps has this feature now a days where you go to setting and it shows you a local IP. Using the IP you can upload files to the app from a locally connected computer. This is very handy if you don't have iTunes to upload files or a usb cable to connect your device.
My question is what is this feature called? Any reference to API/Examples i can look into?

Here is an example of Comic Flow app with the same feature:
[image]

Comment: It appears the app has a built-in web server. One is https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

Comment: @rmaddy any reason to remove the Xcode tag?

Comment: Sure, your question has nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is an IDE. Read the tag's description.